# Problem with dividing pdf page into two in php using dompdf

Tags: php, html, css, dompdf

The following code is from my resume.php file. I have tried to divide the page into two blocks each represented using (.left) and (.right) class. Content on left block is being displayed but on the right side, whatever I write moves to the next page.

```
<?php

// get all the data
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'] == null ? "" : $_POST['middlename'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$designation = $_POST['designation'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$summary = $_POST['summary'];

//get skills
$skills = $_POST['skills']; 

require_once('./dompdf/autoload.inc.php');      

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');



// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$html = "
<html>
<head>
        <style>
                body{
                        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
                }
                .left{
                        background-color: rgb(7,72,70);
                        height:100%;
                        width: 40%;
                        color:white;
                }
                .right{
                        width:60%;
                }
                .image-container{
                        width:2.5in;
                        height:2.5in;
                        background-color:red;
                }
                .name{
                      width:100%;
                      height:0.5in;
                      font-style:bold;
                      font-size: 0.208in;
                      text-align:center;
                }
                .horizontal-line{
                        height:0.0208in;
                        width:60%;
                        margin-left:auto;
                        margin-right:auto;
                        color:white;
                }
                .designation{
                        text-align:center;
                }
                .phone, .email, .address, .about{
                        margin:0.1in;
                }
                .left-heading{
                        margin-left:0.2in;
                        font-style:bold;
                        margin-top:0.2in;
                        margin-bottom:0.2in;
                }
                .left-sub-section{
                        margin-left:0.2in;
                        margin-right:0.2in;
                }
                .right-heading{
                        margin-left:0.3in;
                        margin-bottom:0.2in;
                        margin-top:0.5in;
                }
        </style>
</head>
<body>
        <div class='container'>
                <div class='left'>
                        <div class='image-container'>

                        </div>
                        <div class='name'>
                                $firstname $middlename $lastname
                        </div>
                        <div class='horizontal-line'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='designation'>
                                $designation
                        </div>

                        <div class='left-heading'> 
                                About 
                        </div>
                        <div class='left-sub-section'>
                                <div class='phone'>$phone</div>
                                <div class='email'>$email</div>
                                <div class='address'>$address</div>
                                <div class='about'>$summary</div>
                        </div>

                        <div class='left-heading'> Skills </div>
                        <div class='left-sub-section'> ";

foreach ($skills as $skill){
        $html .= "<div style='margin:0.1in;'> $skill</div>";
}
                                

$html .= "</div>
                </div>
                <div class='right'>
                        <div class='ahivements-section'>
                                <div class='right-heading'>
                                        ACHIEVEMENT
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>";

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="output.pdf"'); // Set filename as "output.pdf" and specify inline disposition

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream(null, ['Attachment' => 0]);
```

I want to get the ACHIEVEMENT section on the right side of the same page.

Comment: Nowhere in your styles are you saying `.left` should be on the left side and `.right` should be right. You set `width`, but that's it. Use `flex` or `grid` to align elements.

Comment: @brombeer thanks for suggestion, I have tried setting the container display to flex but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block` for `.left` and `.right`, so that they can be displayed next to each other, and maybe decrease their width a little bit so that it doesn't add up to exactly 100%, but a little less, plus also maybe use `box-sizing: border-box` on them to include all borders and paddings in those percentage width values. (Use trial and error to find out which percentage values work)

(I am not sure about the current state, but at least older versions of dompdf couldn't handle flex, which would be the ideal solution - therefore my suggestion of inline-blocks)

Comment: I tried using display:inline-block, also played with the width but the results are same. Actually I am not getting what the real problem is or could be!

Comment: If nothing else works, you can try to use a table and have `.left` and `right` as `td`s in one `tr`. Of course, that's semantically not correct, but if it's only for generating a pdf, this won't be a problem. dompdf can really be nasty if it comes to css...

Comment: you are right @Johannes. I tried using table it worked but still suffers some problems like unwanted margin or blank pages due to the height parameter!

Answer (score 0):

I remember struggling with that problem when working with `dompdf`.
You can try to change your "right" and "left" classes to this:

```
.left{
    background-color: rgb(7,72,70);
    color:white;
    top: 0px; 
    left: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 40%; 
    height:100%;
}
.right{
    top: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    position: absolute; 
    width: 60%;
    height:100%;
}
```